# Gas range issue

Tags: range

My gas oven wouldn't start. I replaced the oven igniter and now the oven works but I smell gas, even when it is turned off. If I turn the gas off at the valve, the gas smell goes away. Is this a regulator issue? Where do I go from here?

---

It was leaking at the safety valve. No more gas smell but now the flame is super high. Maybe the regulator?

Answer (score 1):

The ignighter usually has no Inter action with the gas other than switches that turn on the electronics, did you change or mess with any of the gas lines?  I would make up a soap water solution and check every fitting for leaks and tighten. Gas is normally only pressurized at ~3/4 of a psi so there is not much pressure. If after bubble checking all the fittings and tightening any leakers it would be time to call a pro if you smell gas.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I didn't mess with any of the gas lines, I'm not that brave. I checked all the fittings. The only place I found bubbles was at the opening of the safety valve.

Comment: Can you provide a photo of that location I would suggest fighting but am not sure what valve this is in your stove

Comment: It was leaking at the safety valve. No more gas smell but now the flame is super high. Do you think maybe its the regulator?

Comment: The control valves should adjust the flame size I always want more heat on most stoves. The only other thing I know of is the orifice to change from propane or LNG, to natural gas this would make a change but I don't think that is your issue. It would be rare for a gas regulator to go bad for libiality issues it might be a good idea to contact the mfg on things like this if there is the possibility of a problem they may replace it free of charge.